# Compiling error checkinstall

Tags: wine, compiling, checkinstall

Hi I wanna compile my first package (Wine) under Ubuntu (it's also my first day with this OS). I ran ./configure and make, no errors. But when I did checkinstall then I got this back:

```
========================= Installation results ===========================
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools'
make[1]: `makedep' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/libs/port'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/libs/port'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/libs/wine'
version=`(GIT_DIR=../../.git git describe HEAD 2>/dev/null || echo "wine-1.5.22") | sed -n -e '$s/\(.*\)/const char wine_build[] = "\1";/p'` && (echo $version | cmp -s - version.c) || echo $version >version.c || (rm -f version.c && exit 1)
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/libs/wine'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/libs/wpp'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/libs/wpp'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/widl'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/widl'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/winebuild'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/winebuild'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/winedump'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/winedump'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/winegcc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/winegcc'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/wmc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/wmc'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/wrc'
gcc -c -I. -I. -I../../include -I../../include  -D__WINESRC__ -DINCLUDEDIR="\"/usr    /local/include/wine\""   -Wall -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wempty-body -Wignored-qualifiers -Wstrict-prototypes -Wtype-limits -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wwrite-strings -gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -o parser.tab.o parser.tab.c
parser.y: In function ‘rsrcid_to_token’:
parser.y:2841:15: error: ‘YYLEX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
lookahead = YYLEX;
            ^
parser.y:2841:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: *** [parser.tab.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/donbilbo/Downloads/wine-1.5.22/tools/wrc'
make: *** [tools/wrc] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK

Bye.
```